# Why am I getting an error when trying to use .get_text() in python with beautiful soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to follow this [turorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bg9r_yLk7VY&t=2s) on youtube to make a web scraper and I reached a certain part where he was trying to get the title of the product and print it to the screen. However, when I tried to do it I was given an error for `.get_text()` and I don't understand where I went wrong when I copied everything that he had.

And another thing is that when he was typing in `soup.` it showed a list of classes for him but not for me why is that. I am doing this in visual studio code btw

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.amazon.com/Nintendo-Console-Resolution-802-11ac-Surround/dp/B07RGFF98S/ref=sr_1_2?crid=213XSEHLOFP4W&dchild=1&keywords=nintendo+switch&qid=1599079468&sprefix=nintendo%2Caps%2C395&sr=8-2"

headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()

print(title.strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

To get correct response from Amazon server (and not captcha page), also specify `Accept-Language` HTTP header:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.amazon.com/Nintendo-Console-Resolution-802-11ac-Surround/dp/B07RGFF98S/ref=sr_1_2?crid=213XSEHLOFP4W&dchild=1&keywords=nintendo+switch&qid=1599079468&sprefix=nintendo%2Caps%2C395&sr=8-2"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5'
}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
print(title.strip())
```

Prints:

```
Nintendo Switch 32GB Console Video Games w/ 32GB Memory Card | Neon Red/Neon Blue Joy-Con | 1080p Resolution | 802.11ac WiFi | HDMI | Surround Sound | IR Motion Camera
```

Comment: oh okay, i see but what about my another question where he types ```soup.``` and a list of classes or methods showed up for him but it didn't do the same for me.